# regex letters, spaces and accent

Tags: php, regex

I made this regex to filter certain texts before saving it, my idea was to keep only letters, spaces and letters with accents or ñ, but the last two cases, both as accents ñ not work, I hope you can help me.

```
if(preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z .\-]+$/i", $field)){
    return true;
}else{
    return false;
}
```

Comment: add them (letters with accents you need) to your character class, and use the u modifier to handle UTF8 strings.

Comment: Escaping the dash is not needed when it's the last in the `[]`. And you don't need A-Z if you use `/i`. So your regex becomes this: `/^[a-z .-]+$/i`

Comment: @Al.G.: no you don't need to escape the dot in a character class.

Comment: That's new to me, thanks, comment edited :)

Comment: @Al.G. thanks for your answer, this regex not working /^[a-zA-Z \.-]+$/i

Comment: Because you didn't put in accented characters. Put in the characters you want to allow inside the character class `[]` and add the `u` modifier. The `i` is if you want case insensitivity, if you do you won't need the `A-Z` or `a-z` one or the other because they are the same with `i`.

Comment: @chris85 then how would they be? I do not understand very well these expressions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want something like `/^[\pL\pM\p{Zs}.-]+$/u`.

To explain the new bits:

- `\pL` - Matches anything in the Unicode letter category
- `\pM` - Combining marks (e.g. combining diacritics)
- `\p{Zs}` - White-space separators
- `u` - Pattern and subject strings are treated as UTF-8

---

<sub>For more information on Unicode in regular expressions, including Unicode categories, see http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html</sub>

Comment: Thank you! this served to me, in fact I still have many doubts even as the regex leere work so you left me. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can add the accented characters to your cases:

```
    if(preg_match("/^[A-Za-z\u00C0-\u017F\.\-]+$/i",       $field)){
       return true;
    }else{
       return false;
    }
```

Another way is to convert the word into unicode first to sanitize accented chars before you run your regex function

Comment: This is better because is explicitly lists the allowed characters and gives you more control.